# Create gist on github with User ID using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, github

I'm trying to create a gist on github.com using the user ID. Currently I can create anonymous gist with the node-github module.
This is the code

```
github.gists.create({
    "description": "the description for this gist",
    "public": true,
    "files": {
        "BONE101TEST_2.md": {
            "content": "<html><h1>This is a Test!</h1><b>Hello</b><img src=></html>"
        }
    }
 }, function(err, rest) {
      console.log(rest);
  });
```

According to the [github](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#authentication) documentation " to read or write gists on a user’s behalf the gist OAuth scope is required."  This will give me the tokens for the user.
But how do I specify that I want that the gist has to be created using the user X. I'm reading the node-githu [documentation](http://ajaxorg.github.io/node-github/#gists.prototype.create) but doesn't tells me this. Any idea?

**Updated**
I can create a programatic token according to the docs. Still not sure how to identify the id of the user for creating the gist, if the create method doesn't make reference to it.

```
github.authorization.create({
    scopes: ["user", "public_repo", "repo", "repo:status", "gist"],
    note: "what this auth is for",
    note_url: "http://url-to-this-auth-app",
    headers: {
        "X-GitHub-OTP": "two-factor-code"
    }
}, function(err, res) {
    if (res.token) {
        //save and use res.token as in the Oauth process above from now on
    }
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github#authentication

Comment: Also check the test programs https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github/tree/master/test

Comment: That doesn't work, I don't want to request user & password, and the other example it appears it specifies it doesn't work with the V3 of the github API: // Deprecated Gihub API token (seems not to be working with the v3 API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of the links you share with me had the answer. Just modify it.
Here's the code if someone needs it.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var url = Url.parse(req.url);
    var path = url.pathname;
    var query = querystring.parse(url.query);

    if (path == "/" || path.match(/^\/user\/?$/)) {
        // redirect to github if there is no access token
        if (!accessToken) {
            res.writeHead(303, {
                Location: oauth.getAuthorizeUrl({
                    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/github-callback',
                    scope: "user,repo,gist"
                })
            });
            res.end();
            return;
        }

        // use github API
        github.gists.create({
          "description": "the description for this gist",
          "public": true,
          "files": {
            "TEST_2.md": {
              "content": "<html><h1>This is a Test!</h1><b>Hello</b><img src=></html>"
              }
            }
          }, function(err, rest) {
            console.log(rest);
          });
        return;
    }
    // URL called by github after authenticating
    else if (path.match(/^\/github-callback\/?$/)) {
        // upgrade the code to an access token
        oauth.getOAuthAccessToken(query.code, {}, function (err, access_token, refresh_token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.writeHead(500);
                res.end(err + "");
                return;
            }

            accessToken = access_token;

            // authenticate github API
            github.authenticate({
                type: "oauth",
                token: accessToken
            });

            //redirect back
            res.writeHead(303, {
                Location: "/"
            });
            res.end();
        });
        return;
    }

    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end("404 - Not found");
}).listen(3000);
```